# SQL Server - Finding bitwise OR values using query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a business requirement to search through a database table where one of the columns is a bitwise integer and remove the base values from a table.

For example, assume my table/resultset looks like this currently:

```
Value
-----
1
2
16
32
33
```

Notice that 33 is present, which is also 32 | 1. What I need to do is remove the 1 and 32 values to return this:

```
Value
-----
2
16
33
```

Obviously I could do this with looping constructs in SQL - or even in my business logic in C# - but I'm wondering whether this is at all possible using a query?

Comment: Is this a one-off task? If so, then just go with the loops if it is simpler.

Comment: This is just an example, my real-world database will include many instances like this grouped by user IDs, so it would be ideal if there is a way to do this without any loops slowing things down

Comment: I guess I'm asking, do you just need to run the query once to clean up a table, or is this part of an app that will run the query over and over? If it is a one-off, then performance probably wouldn't matter so much. In any case, my answer has a query that you could use in either situation.

Comment: This is something that is part of an app - will run over and over again on table data, so need to filter it down

Comment: In that case, you might be better off adding validation logic to prevent the data you don't want to ever be inserted rather than trying to delete it out after the fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a query that ought to work.

```
DELETE myTable WHERE myTable.Value in
(SELECT T1.Value
FROM myTable T1
CROSS JOIN myTable T2
WHERE T1.Value<>T2.Value AND T1.Value<T2.Value AND ((T1.Value | T2.VALUE)=T2.Value))
```

Comment: Thanks @JohnFx, works good in my little example, shall see if I can fit it into my app proper

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
with cte(Value) as (
    select 1 as Value
    union all
    select 2
    union all
    select 16
    union all
    select 32
    union all
    select 33
)

--select values to be removed
select x1.Value
from cte x1
inner join cte x2 on x1.Value <> x2.Value 
inner join cte x3 on x1.Value <> x3.Value and x2.Value <> x3.Value
where x1.Value | x2.Value = x3.Value
```